# How to route to another internal site with ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an angular material `md-sidenav` with a few links. The main content on the right contains my `ui-view`. Clicking the links uses `ui-router` to open the appropriate content in the main content area.

```
<body ng-app="mainApp" ng-cloak>
    <div layout="column" style="height:100%;">
      <section layout="row" flex>
        <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open=true>
          <md-content layout-padding  layout="column">
            <md-button ui-sref="home" class="md-primary">Home</md-button>
            <md-button ui-sref="map" class="md-primary">Map</md-button>
          </md-content>
        </md-sidenav>
        <md-content flex layout-padding>
          <!-- Main Content -->
          <div ui-view></div>
        </md-content>
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
```

I have another site that is auto-generated with an external tool (generates an index.html, a bunch of javascript, icons, css, etc.). The output of this is hosted internally, however the generated code refers to paths that are relative to itself, not the rest of my site. When I try route to this index.html, it can't find the referenced paths because of this.

Here is my current state:

```
.state('map', {
      url: "/map",
      templateUrl: "components/map/overviewer/index.html",
      controller: "MapCtrl"
    })
```

I found a solution where I can open the page, but I can't figure out how to open it within my main content section. Any ideas?

```
.state('external', {
        onEnter: function($window) {
            $window.open('components/map/overviewer/index.html', '_self');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) to load your internal site.

Create a 'dummy' component in your main site which contains an iframe and use the ui-route to navigate to that. Then have this iframe link to your internal site.